# What is the vertical offset between 2 lines of text in QFont?

Tags: c++, qt, text, qpainter

Is it just `QFontMetrics::height()`, or is it `QFontMetrics::height()+QFontMetrics::leading()`?

For example, in this code:

```
painter.drawText(QRect(x, y, 1000, 1000), "line1");
y += lineOffset;
painter.drawText(QRect(x, y, 1000, 1000), "line2");
y += lineOffset;
painter.drawText(QRect(x, y, 1000, 1000), "line3");
```

What would the value of `lineOffset` need to be in order for the lines to be spaced as if this code had been used:

```
painter.drawText(QRect(x, y, 1000, 1000), "line1\nline2\nline3");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the [documentation](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qfontmetrics.html#lineSpacing) tells you, `lineSpacing()` is the vertical distance between two lines, and it is the sum of `height()` (the height of the font) and `leading()`.